# Правильно ли выражение "встала вспять" (река)

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Правильно ли выражение: "река встала вспять", в смысле повернула назад. Или же "стала вспять".
Не знаю, нужно ли разделять вопросы, вот ещё пример: "войти на путь" или "взойти на путь"(греха).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ни *"встать вспять"*, ни *"стать вспять"* правильными не являются. "Вспять" - это "назад". Как река может "встать назад"? Если вы хотите сказать, что река повернула назад, то правильно будет сказать *"река потекла вспять"*.

*"Войти на путь"* и *"взойти на путь"* хотя формально правильны, в данном контексте звучат довольно чужеродно и режут слух. Устоявшимся выражением является *"встать на путь (греха)"*.

Comment: *"Войти на путь" и "взойти на путь" хотя формально правильны* - нет. Совершенно некорректное использование и по форме и по смыслу.

Answer (score 1):

> "река встала вспять"

Неверно. Вспять река может потечь - по большей части умозрительно.
"Встать" используется ы отношении реки только в значении "покрылась льдом". Есть еще правда, упоминание в библейских историях когда воды Иордана "встали" перед проходом израильтян - то это тоже означает остановку, а не обратное течение.

> "войти на путь" или "взойти на путь"

Никакого оправдания для подобного использования нет. На путь можно только **вступить**. И именно это выражение используется в выражении "вступить на путь греха" 
Или "на порочный путь".

"Взойти" на путь -  возможно только в каких-то полуфантастических контекстах - ну если этот путь на очень высокой насыпи. "Войти" - невозможно даже в таких предположениях. –

"Встать" на путь еще возможно, но вне контекста тоже странно выглядит стилистически.

=======================

> А развернуться вспять река может?

"Развернуться вспять" - нет. Тут, правда, вопрос не столько формального запрета, сколько речевой избыточности. "Развернуться" - уже содержит в себе указаание на движение в обратьном направлении, "вспять" - уже излишнее. "Повернуть вспять" - ну это еще можно, в народно-поэтическом стиле.

Но тут еще проблема сочетаемости со словом "река". Дело в том, что единственное "узаконенное" употребление: "Воды Иордана *потекут вспять*". За ним и стойкий ассоциативный ряд и довольно стройный круг контекста, позволяющий подобное употребление. Это уже сложившееся употребление, не законченный фразеологизм еще, конечно, но уже сопротивляющийся замене отдельных слов. Поэтому употреблять другие варианты надо с большой осторожность, даже если дело касается других рек.

Comment: Предельно ясно. А развернуться вспять река может? (умозрительно). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Лия, "повернуть вспять" выражение вполне употребительное. "Развернуться вспять" тоже возможно, но на слух звучит как-то похуже. Я бы предпочёл сказать "повернуть", но убедительно обосновать не могу.

Comment: @Лия *А развернуться вспять река может* - нет. Подробнее - см. в тексте моего ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Я согласен с @freim в части реки.

По поводу же греха, я бы сказал не "встать на путь греха", а "стать на путь греха".

Мы встаём  -- ну, например, навстречу. А на путь мы не встаём, а становимся.

Comment: Слово "встать" тоже имеет схожее [значение](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), эти слова частично пересекаются. Я думаю, правильно будет и так, и так. Но в целом согласен с вашим замечанием.